# Why do I get strange output when trying to split an integer into decimal digits?

Tags: arrays, c

The numbers are split up perfectly, however when assigned to the char array, there seems to be some memory corruption. In every number bigger or equal to 10000 the number at the **ten thousands** is corrupted and gives a similar output:

```
►     {‼░       ↔             @     a■    ♣
```

```
#include <unistd.h>

void ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    char character[sizeof(int)];
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (nb > 0)
    {
        character[i] = (nb % 10) + 48; // Split up the number into characters
        nb /= 10;   // Remove the number at the ones
        i++;
    }
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        write(1, &character[i - 1], 1);
        i--;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    ft_putnbr(2147483647);
}
```

Output:

```
21474É       ►     →‼░       ↔             @     a■    ♣3647
```

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is not the number of decimal digits of `nb`, in case that's what you were expecting.

Comment: You already got a clue, what is the major difference between numbers less than 10000, and numbers 10000 or larger, in terms of number of digits?

Comment: Try putting `printf("size of int is %zu\n", sizeof(int));` as the very first statement in your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sizeof(int)
```

Does not return number of digits, but size of int in bytes. That means that it returns 4, not 10 (or more).

Comment: To get the number of bytes needed to store the decimal digits as a string, use `(int) ceil(log10(256)*sizeof(int)) + 1` (`+ 1` is needed to store the final `\0` byte).. you'll need to `#include <math.h>`

Comment: In your case you don't seem to store the final `\0` byte but 99% of the time you would want to :)